# jQuery: How can I update input field's value? (data from webSocket)

Tags: jquery, websocket

What I want to achieve is, when I click on any of these result, I want the input field's value change to what I click on. However the `.item-search-result` seems not clickable? I wrote the following code to test out but nothing shows up in the console [screenshot for console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vttV.png), and the whole result list is still there (the `closeResult()` function suppose to close it).

```
$('.item-search-results').on('click', () => {
    console.log('hi!');
    closeResult();
  })
```

How can I properly update the value of the input field?

All my webSocket js:

```
$(function () {
  let activeInput;

  let webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/autocomplete");
  webSocket.onopen = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('connected to WebSocket!');
  };

  webSocket.onmessage = (msgEvent) => {
    /* results shows {"results":{"results":[{..}]}}.
    results.results shows {results:[{..}]}
    results.results.results shows [{...}], which is an array */
    let results = JSON.parse(msgEvent.data);
        resultsArr = results.results.results;
    console.log(resultsArr);
    appendResults();
  };

  webSocket.onclose = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  };

  webSocket.onerror = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('there\'s an error', error);
  };

  /**
  *  Render results to UI
  */
  const appendResults = () => {
    //create <div class="item-search-results"></div>
    let itemSearchResults = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'item-search-results');
    //for each result that received, create a div for it for give it a unique id
    $.each(resultsArr, (index, value) => {
      let resultDivs = $('<div>' + value['name'] + '</div>').attr('id', 'item-search-results-' + index);
      //append these divs to <div class="item-search-results"></div>
      resultDivs.appendTo(itemSearchResults);
    });
    //append the <div class="item-search-results"></div> to its closest <td class="item-search-container"></td>
    itemSearchResults.appendTo($(activeInput).closest('.item-search-container'));
  }

  /**
  *  Close the autocomplete lists
  */
  const closeResult = () => {
    $('.item-search-results').remove();
  };

  /**
  *  Change input field's value
  */
  $('.item-search-results').on('click', () => {
    console.log('hi!');
    closeResult();
  })

    // $(document).on('click', () => {
    //   closeResult();
    // });

  /**
  *  Request data
  */
  $('.add-items-table').on('input', '.item-input', (e) => {
    activeInput = e.target;
    let value = e.target.value;
    webSocket.send(value);
    //console.log(value);
  });

})
```

Original HTML:

```
<td class="item-search-container">
    <input class="item-input" id="item-input-0" type="search" name="item" value="">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here is what I did:
Add `on click` while looping, store the text to a variable and then pass it to the `updateInputVal` function

```
$.each(resultsArr, (index, value) => {
      let resultDiv = $('<div>' + value['name'] + '</div>').attr('id', 'item-search-results-' + index);
      //add click listener to update input field's value
      resultDiv.on('click', () => {
        //set the value and pass it to the function
        let newText = resultDiv[0].innerText;
        updateInputVal(newText);
      });
      //append these divs to <div class="item-search-results"></div>
      resultDiv.appendTo(itemSearchResults);
    });
```

And here's the `updateInputVal` function

```
const updateInputVal = (newText) => {
    $(activeInput)[0].value = newText;
    closeResult();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of an input by using jquerys .val()

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".item-search-results").click(function(){

        var newtext = //new value

        $('input.item-input').val(newtext);

    });
});
```

edit:

```
$(document).on("click",".item-search-results",function() {
     var newtext = //new value
     $('input.item-input').val(newtext);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Although `.click` doesn't work because the `.item-search-results` is generated dynamically.

Comment: That's ok, I've updated it so it should work on generated elements.